# Postgres: Column updated but not detected.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So i initially had a foreign id `tutor_id` as type `string`. So i ran the following migrations.

`change_column(:profiles, :tutor_id, 'integer USING CAST(tutor_id AS integer)')`

The problem is that there was data already created which initially contained the `tutor_id` as type `string`. I did read however that by using `CAST`, the data should be converted into an integer.

So just to confirm i went into `heroku run rails console` to check the `tutor_id` of the profiles and `tutor_id.is_a? Integer` returns `true`.

However i am currently getting this error

`ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = text at character 66`

Why is that so? Is the only way out to delete the data and to recreate it?

(I'm assuming the information provided above is enough to draw a conclusion, else i will add the relevant information too.)

Answer (score 1):

You also have to update your code to use integers rather than strings. This error happens because your code somewhere still has the column type as string and the query sent has the value sent as '123'. PostgreSQL doesn't do automatic type conversions so it's telling you it can't do the comparison.